# Replace mixin to reuse props in different components - react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In my vue checkbox component, i am using size mixin for calculating different sizes of checkboxes. While replacing the vue component into react component, i have checked this mixin problem. So, i came to know we can do same in react using higher order function.

**here is my mixin**

```
<script>
    export default{
        name: "size-mixin",
        props: {
            size: {
                validator: function (value) {
                    return ['large','medium', 'small'].indexOf(value) !== -1
                },
            },
            
            small: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            
            sm: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            
            medium: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            
            md: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            
            large: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            
            lg: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I am using this mixin in my component like this below:

```
export default {
  name: 'myCheckboxComponent',
    mixins: [SizeMixin],
    props: {
    
    // different component props
  }
  // props of mixins use here for computation
  
   computed: {
        defineSize() {
            if(this.size) {return this.size}
            if(this.medium || this.md) {return 'medium'}
            if(this.large || this.lg) {return 'large'}
            if(this.small || this.sm) {return 'small'}
            if(this.urInput) {return this.urInput.size}
            return this.defaultSize;
        },
    }
}
```

In Parent component, i am using checkbox by defining size only

```
<my-checkbox-component size="medium" />
```

I am trying to do like this but not sure i am in right way or not . As i am not that much familiar with react

```
    export const withSizeCheckBox = (Component, sizeProps) => props => {
    const propsToUse = {...sizeProps};

    return <Component {...propsToUse} {...props}/>;
};
```

**I am not sure how to approach this in react hooks reusing size props**

**So my question is in react hooks how to re use those size props?**

1. As those size props are going to use in different react components.
2. I am using react hooks so how to reuse/replace above mixin in react components?

Comment: It would be helpful to share the ***React*** code you are trying to generate and use, and more clearly explain what the issue is with that code.

Comment: I am not sure how to use those mixins props like it is used vue component computed property

Comment: I don't see any React code so I don't think it's clear what you are trying to do in React.

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating with the React HOC. I don't see overt issues with the implementation, but if you could share how you are using this `withSizeCheckBox` HOC to decorate a component and what is passed to it it may help clear up any confusion, help us see what any issues may be. Are you seeing any errors, or is it just not working as you expect? What is the observed behavior vs the expected behavior?

Comment: I have edited my question. There are  1. component props  2. reusable props . Those reusable props i want to use in different component. In react hooks way, how to do that?

Comment: Person with React and Vue experience here, looks like you are migrating components from Vue to React. There is not such thing as mixins in React, you will need to use useEffect hook to perform that logic once the component loads. In addition to that your question is not complete and hence we can't help you.
Please provide full code or Codepen.